# Good textbooks on nonlinear electrodynamics?

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, non-linear-systems

Looking for suggestions for a good textbook on nonlinear electrodynamics, not going into optics immediately as most textbooks tend to do but perhaps a rigorous mathematical exposition on the foundations of the theory itself.

Comment: Jackson I suppose. Pretty standard graduate text.

Comment: I agree, J.D. Jackson's book _Classical Electrodynamics_ is about as rigorous as you will find for the entire field of E&M (there are more detailed texts/papers on specific subjects, but he references many of them anyways).

Comment: Thanks, I have Jackson's textbook with me. I'll have to sit down with it and study through it carefully.